# MUI toggle switch not changing display and value with a single click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am having troubles with a Material UI toggle switch that I am using on my current project.  When I console log the values the initial value when the component loads is correct.  But if I was to click the switch to say change from 'yes' to 'no', the switch flip will properly render displaying 'no' as selected, the console log fires again but the value still says 'yes'.  If I click the switch a second time to try to flip it back to 'no' the toggle switch just re-renders without flipping, the console log fires again, and the value is now updated to 'no'. So basically the first click flips the toggle, the second click is flipping the value.  I have used this same toggle previously with no issues, so can someone tell me what I need to fix to get this toggle flipping the switch and the value on a single click?

**Handling the Input Change:**

```
    const handleInputChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setValues({
            ...values,
             [name]: ( typeof value === 'string' ? (value).replace(/ +(?= )/g, '').trimStart() : value ) 
            // removes leading space & multiple spaces if value is a string
        });
    };
```

**The Switch as called from the Form:**

```
      <ToggleSwitch
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          label1='No'
          label2='Yes'
          name='useForCalcs'
          value={values.useForCalcs}
       />
```

**The ToggleSwitch Component:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Box, Switch, Typography} from '@material-ui/core';

export default function ToggleSwitch(props) {
  const { label1, label2, name, onChange, value} = props;
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);
  const convertToEventParams = (name, value) => ({ target: { name, value } });
  const curValue = value === 1 ? true : false;
  const handleSwitch = e => { setChecked(e.target.checked); };

  React.useEffect(() => { setChecked(curValue); }, [curValue]); // re-renders the toggle switch with every change to checked value

  const handleChecked = e => {
    handleSwitch(e);
    onChange(convertToEventParams(name, (checked ===  false ? 1 : 0))); // converts True/False to 1/0 values
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <Typography>
        {label1}
        {<Switch
          name={name}
          checked={checked}
          value={checked}
          onChange={handleChecked}
          inputProps={{'aria-label': 'switch'}}
        />}
        {label2}
      </Typography>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're handling the state and the checked value in your ToggleSwitch component. You have both local state (checked) and a prop (value) that you're trying to synchronize.

To fix this issue and ensure that the switch and value are synchronized correctly

you're passing the value prop from the parent component, you can directly use that prop to determine the state of the switch.
You can simplify the component code by removing unnecessary state and effects.

You can directly use the value prop to determine the initial state of the switch and update the parent component using the onChange function.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Box, Switch, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

export default function ToggleSwitch(props) {
  const { label1, label2, name, onChange, value } = props;

  const handleChecked = () => {
    const newValue = value === 0 ? 1 : 0; // Toggle the value
    onChange({ target: { name, value: newValue } });
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <Typography>
        {label1}
        <Switch
          name={name}
          checked={value === 1}
          onChange={handleChecked}
          inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'switch' }}
        />
        {label2}
      </Typography>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, and with 1/2 the code!